# How to retrieve in a .js function the target value of a form which comes from an other template?

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, function, meteor

Hello I'm new on meteor and I would like to retrieve the value of a form in a template thanks to an Event in my .js file. 
It worked when I was using a simple value in my select menu : I retrieved the value of my form with help an Event and I sent it in a Function. 
But now, I am using a template which gives (with #for each) all the values disponible in my collection to supply my select options with all the existant elements. 
The problem is I don't succeed to retrieve the value selected in my form from the client.
Thank you for your help.

Here is a part of my code :

```
 <template name="searchBar">
    <div class="searchBar">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <select name="make">
            {{#each makes}}
                {{>make}}
            {{/each}}
        </select>
        <select name="model">
            {{#each cars}}
                {{>model}}
            {{/each}}
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Prix maximum"/>
        <input type="text" name="quickSearch" placeholder="Mots-clés" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-info" type="submit" value="Rechercher">Rechercher</button> 
    </form> 
    </div>
</template>

<template name="make"> 
  <option>{{make}}</option>
</template>

Template.searchBar.events({
    "submit form": function (event) {
      var make = event.target.make.value;
      var model = event.target.model.value;
      var price = event.target.price.value;
      var quickSearch = event.target.quickSearch.value;

      Meteor.call("findCar", make, model, price, quickSearch);
      return false;
    }
  });


findCar: function (quickSearch,make,model,price) {
    console.log("fonction called");
    console.log("make"); // It send : make instead of the real make
    var carsFound = Cars.find({make:make, model:model, price:price}).fetch(); 
    console.log(carsFound);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use the passed in event object, I sometimes find it is easier to use jQuery (which is natively used in Meteor) selector's to find input values.

If you added an id to your select:

```
<select name="make" id="make">
    {{#each makes}}
        {{>make}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

You can access it in your event as such:

```
$("#make").val();
```

**Tip**: If you want to avoid jQuery and use the built in DOM objects, I find it really helpful to use the debugger in Firefox or Chrome.  They allow you to inspect the object properties in detail.